# Grounding lines to power LEDs, switch in electronic device

Tags: grounding

Grounding lines to power LEDs, switch in electronic device

I'm self taught. My question concerns ground.

This is the bottom of a plastic device. Above, there is battery and LEDs.
Positive feed (s+) enters south, at (A) it connects to line (s1) to a switch terminal (t1), and line (r+) to recharge port (p+). At (B) line (s2) from switch terminal (t2) enters to connect to line (s3) that connects to LED#1 pos. pad (#1+). LED#1 neg. pad (#1-) connects to line (s4) that connects to  LED#2 pos. pad (#2+). LED#2 neg. pad (#2-) connects to line (s5), which connects to negative feed (s-) and line (r-) in area (C).

[image: lines]

Lines (s+), (r+), (s3), (s4), (s5), (r+) are in channels. Copper lined?

Areas (A), (B), (C) -- copper lined?

(r+) and (r-) feed into isolated tubes. Copper?

(s3) runs from (#1-) tp (#2+). Ground issues?

[image: channels for connections]

Thank you for assistance. I am familiar with PCB. Did not know if grounding issues present in wiring up 'old school.' From responses, do not think it is. Greatly appreciate.

Comment: "Copper lined?" You have the device; you tell us. If you don't have enough knowledge to tell please add a clear photo of the device. Is the device working? If not, what is it doing? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: You're using a lot of non-standard terminology and symbols, and that makes it very hard to understand what you're asking. A wire should be drawn as a single line, not two parallel lines. Connections between wires should not have names, and they should be drawn as dots, not rectangles. All of the wires that meet at a connection should have the same name. All of the terminals of a component should be next to each other, with no wires in between them. (cont'd...)

Comment: Every component should be shown on the diagram somehow (preferably using the correct symbol, but if you use a rectangle for every component, that's not terrible). If you follow those rules when you're making diagrams, then your diagrams will be much, much easier to understand. Besides that, I don't really understand a lot of the words you're using. When you say "lines," I don't know what that means; do you mean "wires"? I don't know what "channels" means. I don't know what "isolated tubes" are. Most importantly, I have no idea what the question "Copper lined?" means. What do you mean by that?

Comment: I forgot to mention: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please try to clarify what you're asking, and I hope we can give you the answer you're looking for!

Comment: @TannerSwett maybe the black lines are the gaps between copper areas

Comment: What is this device?   Can you show a couple more views of it?  The more information you provide, the more chance someone can answer your questions.

Comment: [Here's a schematic that I drew](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BSUbv.png) based on your diagram and your description. Please feel free to add it to your post; I think it will help other readers to understand your device.

Comment: I will mention that lining a plastic channel with copper is not a technique I've ever heard of and I'm not aware of any reason why it would help anything. Do you have some particular concern about your circuit that you think might be alleviated by lining the channels with copper? Also, do you have some particular reason to think that the connection between LED1- and LED2+ might cause ground issues? It sounds like you have some concerns about your circuit as designed (without the channels), but we don't understand why you're concerned about those things.

Comment: "*I would like accept Tanner's answer.*"  You can't because nobody has posted an answer yet, only comments. You still haven't said what the device is for and how is supposed to work and Tanner has no way of knowing which "answer" you are referring to. Can you address these issues in your question (not in the comments). Thanks.

Comment: @TannerSwett the OP is asking for the circiut, please post as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Before I try to answer your questions, I've redrawn your wiring diagram to make it easier to read. My diagram shows the exact same circuit as your diagram, but mine uses standard symbols and conventions, so this diagram will be much, much easier for other people to understand.

Here, S+ and S- are the "feed" and P+ and P- are the recharge port.

[image: Schematic of the LED device]

Now I'll see if I can answer your questions.

It looks like you have a plastic board with grooves in it for the wires to run in, and you're asking if you should line the grooves with copper. My response is that that doesn't sound like it would be useful. I've never heard of anyone doing such a thing before, and I'm not aware of any reason why it would help anything.

I'm interesting in hearing your reason for asking whether or not those grooves should be lined with copper. It sounds like you have some sort of concern here, but in order to help you here, I would need to know what your concern is.

Your other question is whether or not the connection between the cathode (or "negative terminal") of LED1 and the anode (or "positive terminal") of LED2 may cause ground issues. My response is that that looks like a completely ordinary, normal connection, and that connection isn't even related to grounding at all, so there doesn't seem to be any reason to suspect that it might cause ground issues.

However, I do notice one potential problem with your circuit, which is that there doesn't seem to be any current-limiting resistor in series with LED1 and LED2. LEDs usually have resistors in series with them, because without a resistor, even a small amount of excess voltage can easily damage the LEDs or cause them to draw too much current.